# Detect drop with jQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm playing with jQuery Sortable (http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) to display nested lists, move elements and then save the final results. The final goals is to manage a site structure/hierarchy by displaying categories and pages with drag & drop possibilities.

Displaying the list, dragging and dropping elements and saving the output works fine. I now would like to detect drop events to indicate which elements have been moved. This would help me to avoid updating the whole site structure while only a few elements have moved.

My nested list looks like this:

```
<ol id="structure" class="tree serialization">
  <li class="placeholder-children ui-droppable">
    LABEL
    <ol>
       <li class="placeholder-children ui-droppable">LABEL</li>
       <li class="placeholder-children ui-droppable">LABEL
         <ol>
          <li class="placeholder-children ui-droppable">LABEL</li>
         </ol>
       </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

LI are all droppable and draggable

everything is initialized with:

```
<script>
  $(function  () 
    {
        $("ol.tree").sortable();
    })
</script>
```

Now comes the difficult part, I try to detect drop events.

The following one doesn't work at all:

```
$( ".placeholder-children" ).droppable({
drop: function( event, ui ) {
alert('dropped');
}
});
});
```

This one works but freezes my page:

```
<script>
$("ol.tree").sortable(
            {
                group: 'serialization',
                onDrop: function (item, container, _super) 
                    {
                        alert('dropped!');
                    }
            });
</script>
```

This code triggers the expected alert but the dragging freezes and I can't modify anything in my list anymore. It's like the whole screen is frozen as I can't move or click anything anymore. I need to reload the page get out of it.

Note: without the alert, it also freezes.

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**
I have added a JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/t9mp80yw/
but I don't know how to call the .js file so that the script can be initialized. I have tried to added the file hosted on my server but it looks like jsfiddle doesn't accept external files.

**UPDATE2**
I have tried the script with Firefox and Internet Explorer, same issue.

Thanks a lot

Laurent

PS: not shown here but jQuery, jQuery UI, jQuery Sortable are correctly loaded

Comment: alert generally freezes your pages and requires user input before progressing and so you'll lose your drag focus. use console.log instead for debugging if you'd like. Otherwise that drop handler should be fine.

Comment: Hi Cowboybebop, you're right but in this case, even without the alert, the drag&drop freezes. If I remove the drop event detection, there is no freeze anymore.

Comment: Can you re-create the issue with a jsFiddle?

Comment: yes a jsfiddle would help.

Comment: @user3638239 Why are you using both jquery sortable plugin and `jquery-ui sortable`..?

Comment: TJ, yes both are loaded.

Comment: Jsfiddle is going to be difficult, the script is built in my cms but I'll give it a try tonight.

Comment: I have tried the script without loading jsquery-ui but it lead me to the same issue.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the right scripts: http://jsfiddle.net/xdjn2wqp/

Comment: @user3638239 Why are you loading both..?seems like a very strange thing to do. Is this question about jquery ui sortable..? It doesn't look so judging by the accepted answer. If so, please un-tag jquery ui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onDrop function needs you to do certain things.

From http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#nested

```
onDrop: function (item, container, _super) {
    container.el.removeClass("active")
    _super(item)
}
```

It looks like super is a callback that needs to be called if you override `onDrop`. Replace your `onDrop` function with this and it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/xdjn2wqp/2/

The best way to learn a new library is to paste in some of their working example code and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log('Sortable stop');
}
```

Comment: Please explain the answer

Comment: add it to .sortable({}) instead of onDrop